# Soundex in JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi im using the Hibernate Entity Manger to perform all the CRUD.
I just want to run the query `SELECT soundex('asdf')` through the entity manger.
Can some one please give the solution for firing these query over database using **JPA**

Answer (score 1):

**put @query annotation in method of repository class.**

**for example:-**
public static final String SQL = "SELECT projectId FROM projects";

@Query(value = SQL , nativeQuery = true)
public List findProjects();